# Can I run JetBrains dotCover in a Linux Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, dotcover

I'm building and running a .NET Core application inside a Linux-based Docker container. I'm having trouble figuring out if dotCover is cross-platform? I want to either...

- Install and run dotCover inside the Docker container (that is `$ dotcover analyse ...`).
- Or run some compatible instrumentation during the test step inside the Docker container and send a file back to the host, where I can run dotCover on the file.

---

Obviously, I'm already using the dotCover ["server package"](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/download/#section=commandline). It doesn't indicate that it's cross-platform. So, maybe I'm stuck trying to find another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resurrecting this one more time for the next reader. Jetbrains released a cross-platform console runner.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/08/26/cross-platform-dotcover-console-runner-whats-new-dotcover-2019-2/

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to resurrect an old post, but I'm going to for anyone landing on this from the internet.

Currently no, all of the ReSharper products from JetBrains are not cross platform. Windows is a requirement under the system requirements page.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/system_requirements.html

This means that it is not readily available to run in a linux-based container or linux environment.